# Exponential decrease in the the coordinates (x,y)

Tags: java, math, coordinates, exponential

I planned to fly a bubble starts from origin (0,0) and trace the path as shown below. But the path is not so smooth. I could see the y axis need exponential increase in Y axis till the peak and it has to exponentially decrease. Could you please help to correct the below code to get the path like this.

[image]

**Code:**

```
private void createBubbleForBurst() { 

    int coordCount= 0;  
    float tempRowCoord = 0;
    float tempColCoord = 0;

    //Q1 side Bubbles
    while (!Q1BubbleCoordinatesDone){  
        if (coordCount<200){
            tempColCoord = tempColCoord - colMovementIdx; 
            tempRowCoord = tempRowCoord + rowMovementIdx;
        }else{  
            tempColCoord = tempColCoord - colMovementIdx - 0.3f; 
            tempRowCoord = tempRowCoord - rowMovementIdx + 0.3f;
            if(coordCount>320){
                Q1BubbleCoordinatesDone =true;
            }
        }  
        coordCount++;
        Bubble b = new Bubble(BURST_BALL_WHITE,tempColCoord,tempRowCoord);
        bubbleList.add(b); 
    } 

}
```

With this code, I can get the path as shown below

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The issue with your code is that you are not tracking velocity. Action under gravity means that object is accelerated towards the ground over time.

```
private double height;
private double velocity;
static private double GRAVITY = -10.0;

public void tick(double elapsedTime) {
    velocity += gravity * elapsedTime;
    height += velocity * elapsedTime;
    if (height < 0)
        height = 0;
}
```

That will give you an approximation of movement under gravity (which decreases in accuracy as the elapsed time between ticks increases). I've ignored horizontal movement here for simplicity but you can use a similar technique to implement drag. It's hard to tell from your question if that's required. If not then horizontal velocity is constant.